# FreeType2 Cross-compiling for Android

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, cross-compiling, freetype2

I was able to compile Freetype2 library for arm, arm64, x86, x86_64 architectures. These are steps I done to compile it.

1. **Created standalone toolchains for architectures mentioned above.** 
   `make_standalone_toolchain.py \
   --arch arm64 \
   --api 26 \
   --stl=libc++ \
   --install-dir=my-arm64-toolchain`
2. **Set some envirement variables**

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/my-toolchain/bin
   target_host=aarch64-linux-android
   export AR=$target_host-ar
   export AS=$target_host-as
   export CC=$target_host-gcc
   export CXX=$target_host-g++
   export LD=$target_host-ld
   export STRIP=$target_host-strip
   export CFLAGS="-fPIE -fPIC"
   export LDFLAGS="-pie"
   ```
3. **Configure freetype for compilation**

`./configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/home/freetype-arm64 --without-zlib --without-harfbuzz --with-png=no`

4. **And finally make && install**

Compilation was successfull and I was able to get Static freetype library.

I added library to my android studio libs folder.
This is folder structure for library:

```
libs---freetype
    |---${ANDROID_ABI}
         |---include
             |---freetype2
                 |---freetype
                     ---|Bunch of header files
                 |---ftbuild.h
         |---lib
             |---libfreetype.a
```

**This is my CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_definitions("-DGLM_FORCE_SIZE_T_LENGTH -DGLM_FORCE_RADIANS")

add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/glm)

add_library(freetype STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(freetype PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/freetype/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libfreetype.a)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -Wall")
add_library(native-lib SHARED
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
        src/main/cpp/graph.cpp
        src/main/cpp/text.cpp
        src/main/cpp/graphDataWorker.cpp
        )
target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/freetype/${ANDROID_ABI}/include/freetype2)                       

target_link_libraries(native-lib
                  android
                  freetype
                  GLESv2
                  EGL
                  glm
                  atomic
                  log
                  OpenSLES
                  )
```

The problem is that I can use library inside my code and android studio is not giving me any errors, but then i try to run application it gives me this error:

`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

PS:  I Can't see freetype headers in android studio file tree aswell, but can see other libraries.

**Question:** Am I importing library in a wrong way or this is cross-compilation issue and if so how to do it properly?
I done a lot of research on this issue and was unable to find a solution
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The library import doesn't seem wrong by the look of your CMakeLists.txt .. The linker tells to 'use -v to see invocation' ; maybe it would tell you if the correct library is being linked. The fact you can't see freetype includes is weird though

Comment: @brainsandwich Thanks for comment. It says `ld: ../../../../libs/freetype/arm64-v8a/lib/libfreetype.a(ftinit.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62) ../../../../libs/freetype/arm64-v8a/lib/libfreetype.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format`  and EM:62 stands for x86_64. Maybe compilation process is using wrong libs to link against? Is this possible?

Comment: i think i had same problem. do you use stl port for compilation? https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Answer (score 4):

Unless you mixed paths when installing your build of FreeType2, it seems that the compilation of the library is incorrect, since the linker complains about the library being for x86_64 architecture.

On Linux, usually you can check the architecture the library is built for with command `file`. Another way to check the architecture is to use the `objdump` tool that is shipped with Android NDK (if I remember correctly it is generated with a toolchain as well). Its name follows the same pattern than the compiler/linker/... tools, `$target_host-objdump`.

I would recommend to compile FreeType2 using CMake instead of autotools, at least in my case I successfully did it that way.

---

Here is a sample of CMake configuration I wrote to cross-compile FreeType2 for Android. It is a little complex because it is part of a project where I build several libraries.

The idea is that my CMake configuration uses `ExternalProject` to download and compile Freetype. My top-level CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE}=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE}}
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE}=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE}}
  -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}
  -DCMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS=${CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS}
)
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=OFF -DLIBTYPE=SHARED)
else()
  list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DLIBTYPE=STATIC)
endif()
if(DEFINED ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR)
  get_filename_component(_toolchain_dir ${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR} ABSOLUTE)
  list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=${_toolchain_dir})
endif()
if(DEFINED CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI)
  list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI})
endif()

if(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
  get_filename_component(_toolchain_file ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} ABSOLUTE)
  list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${_toolchain_file})
endif()

add_subdirectory(freetype)
```

So the variable `DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS` contains appropriate CMake arguments for cross-compiling that reflect my current CMake configuration. Under directory freetype, the CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
# freetype/CMakeLists.txt
project(freetype)

include(ExternalProject)

if(NOT FREETYPE_GIT_REPOSITORY)
  set(FREETYPE_GIT_REPOSITORY "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/freetype/freetype2.git")
endif()

set(FREETYPE_GIT_REPOSITORY "${FREETYPE_GIT_REPOSITORY}"
  CACHE STRING "Git repository for library Freetype."
)

if(NOT FREETYPE_GIT_TAG)
  set(FREETYPE_GIT_TAG "VER-2-9")
endif()

set(FREETYPE_GIT_TAG "${FREETYPE_GIT_TAG}"
  CACHE STRING "Tag or branch of Git repository to build."
)

message(STATUS "Freetype Git repository: ${FREETYPE_GIT_REPOSITORY}")
message(STATUS "Freetype Git tag: ${FREETYPE_GIT_TAG}")

externalproject_add(freetype
  GIT_REPOSITORY "${FREETYPE_GIT_REPOSITORY}"
  GIT_TAG "${FREETYPE_GIT_TAG}"
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/freetype/src"
  BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/freetype/build"
  CMAKE_ARGS ${DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS}
)
```

Basically this CMakeLists.txt uses ExternalProject to download and compile FreeType2 in the build directory.

And I use a toolchain file for Android:

```
# android.cmake
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Android")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN ${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR})
```

Sorry if it is overly complex; it comes from a project where I was playing with cross-compiling for Android. I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you tell me how to I should integrate your top level cmakelists.txt to my cmakelists.txt? And btw would this work if my main developement machine is windows?

Comment: I get error while executing externalproject_add. Error comes from this if statement `if(NOT GIT_EXECUTABLE)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "error: could not find git for clone of ${name}")
    endif()` inside ExternalProject.cmake

Comment: @VygintasB Probably Git is not found because it is not in your PATH variable; I copy-pasted the content of my CMake configuration out of lazyness, but you don't need something that complicated. The simplest you could do is to directly generate a build directory from FreeType sources using CMake, and use a toolchain file to tell to CMake that you want to cross-compile for Android, just like you would do with your own project. Anyway, it should work on Windows, since the point of CMake is to provide an environment that is system-agnostic.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your example was not quite enough for me, but it gave me quite important insights of how cmake works for cross compilation.

Comment: @VygintasB Glad that you found out how to solve your problem!

Comment: @VygintasB I am facing the same error as you. Can you please mention how you fixed this error? It will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @varunkr `if (DEFINED ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR)
    get_filename_component(_toolchain_dir ${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR} ABSOLUTE)
    list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=${_toolchain_dir})
endif ()
if (DEFINED CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI)
    list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI})
endif ()

if (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    get_filename_component(_toolchain_file ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} ABSOLUTE)
    list(APPEND DEVENV_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${_toolchain_file})
endif ()` these lines were crucial